# Help with denoising signal and periodogram analysis resources

Tags: signal-analysis, power-spectral-density, machine-learning, denoising, time-series

This is a cross posting from the crossvalidated stack exchange as I thought this may be a better forum to ask.

I have a dataset consisting of respiratory time series signals of different lengths obtained from different groups of patients. I want to either classify or cluster the patients using these timeseries by using the commonalities of the time series of each group. However, I have no experience in dsp.

1. Firstly, I am confused if I am supposed to filter my signals to get rid of any frequencies above the Nyquist frequency. My sampling frequency is 32Hz and my time series is somewhat noisy and has some artifacts. I am also unsure of which filter to select for this.
2. Secondly, I wanted to look at the periodogram and the average power spectral density at each frequency within a group - but I am not sure if I understand the periodogram very well - if I have different time series lengths then my periodogram length will vary too, so I am not sure how this comparison can be made.

Being from Pure Math, I know Fourier analysis purely from the perspective of functions and using Fourier transforms to obtain the coefficients that describe the projection of these functions onto an orthonormal system. With periodograms however, I noticed that the x-axis represents sample frequencies. I am confused with the distinction between sampling frequencies vs. underlying frequencies of the generating function (say I have $\sin(2\pi x)$ sampled at 10Hz, does the periodogram characterize the 1Hz underlying frequency of the function?)

Any resources on understanding how to analyze and remove noisy components of time signals from a machine learning perspective would be much appreciated! Due to time constraints, I have shied away from long textbooks on digital signal processing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not on-topic, but: You're in a hazardous area; been there.  Especially if you are dealing with people with respiratory problems.  You need the Capnometry Atlas (name might be wrong), that I had, and reference designs from the past.  If you are under time pressure, I would definitely hire a capnometry consultant (probably a retired doctor); not a EE like me :)  These signals are tough and  (justifiably) subject to legal oversight.  You have to deal with the patients and the experience/expectations of medical professionals with years of experience.

Comment: The given answers are correct, be aware that any out-of-band leakage gets "aliased" into your signal band and lead to incorrect analysis.

Comment: Additional you can read https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5464224/
 Frequency ventilation is rated as having 40Hz primary.  Of course, it's artificial, but I  think occasionally used and it would be a "signal".

Answer (score 4):

> Firstly, I am confused if I am supposed to filter my signals to get rid of any frequencies above the Nyquist frequency. My sampling frequency is 32Hz and my time series is somewhat noisy and has some artifacts. I am also unsure of which filter to select for this.

That ship has sailed.

Let $S=\left\{\left.\alpha e ^{i(\omega t+\varphi)}\right|\alpha > 0, 0\le \varphi <2\pi, \omega \in \mathbb R\right\}$, i.e. the set of all distinct complex sinusoid with an amplitude, frequency and phase.

Then $(S,\cdot)$ is a commutative semigroup (proof trivial).

Introducing the equivalence relation $\sim: a\sim b \iff a\left(\frac{n}{r}\right)= b\left(\frac{n}{r}\right) \forall n\in\mathbb Z$ ("two signals are identical after sampling with rate $r$"), we see that signals $s_l=\alpha e^{i(\omega_l t + \varphi)}, l=1,2,\ldots$ are $s_1\sim s_2$ if $\frac{\omega_1-\omega_2}{2\pi}=nr, n\in\mathbb Z$, i.e. we can't tell signals apart after sampling if their frequency differed by a multiple of the sampling rate.

Let's formalize this: $T=\left\{\alpha e^{i([ft+\phi]\mod 2\pi)}\right\}$ is a quotient semigroup of $S$, i.e. $T\preceq S$, and each of the elements is a leader of a $\sim$-equivalence class – and this homomorpism $S\mapsto T$ is in fact sampling, which, as we can see above, is not bijective.

Hence, all the original frequency components from $S$ got mapped to some component from $T$ with frequency normalized to the sampling frequency. That mapping is called *aliasing*.

What an anti-alias filter $h$ does is

$$h(s): S\mapsto S, h=\begin{cases}
s, & f< f_\text{nyquist}\\
0 & \text{else,}
\end{cases}
$$

and as you'll figure out when inserting $h(s)$ above is that this yields only the elements that are not aliased to a different frequency.

Thus, everything that "survives" $h$ will also "survive" aliasing without undergoing a change in frequency.

So, if you needed an anti-aliasing filter, it's now too late. Go and do your recording again.

> Secondly, I wanted to look at the periodogram and the average power spectral density at each frequency within a group - but I am not sure if I understand the periodogram very well - if I have different time series lengths then my periodogram length will vary too, so I am not sure how this comparison can be made.

In that case, the periodogramm is not a useful mapping on its own – you'll need to add something like a truncation / padding operation to bring all signals to the same duration, for example. At which point the periodogram doesn't seem to be a sensible approach anymore.

Comment: Ooh thanks for the wonderful explanation! One more question I have now: say I want to downsample my signal to make computations easier (Currently I cannot run anything on multiple signal with more than 1million samples). My sampling frequency is 32 Hz and I want to go down to 8Hz. From what I've read, I have to decimate this and remove frequencies that lie above 4 Hz. However, in the literature on respiratory signals, they used an iir Butterworth lowpass filter of 1.2 Hz to reduce frequencies to the domain of interest. Now I am confused on what order these two operations should be done in?

Comment: I don't know *what* you're doing with your signal, but I promise that a 32 Hz sampling rate is laughably low, and computational efficiency doesn't play a role here; all humans ever attached to a breathing analysis device could never breathe enough for this to ever become "much data" for a modern PC... If you want to decimate, the same sampling approach applies, and you hence must filter **before** you decimate, not after. And a Butterworth doesn't seem to be an appropriate filter choice here.

Comment: Ouch... All I can say is that I am not in charge of the data collection and have been hired to do ML research on it. I left this up to the domain experts. The recording is about 8-10 hours which makes it very long for things such as dynamic time warping distance matrix computations. Would you be able to expand on the Butterworth filter? I got the info out of a 2016 paper titled "Utility of AdaBoost to Detect Sleep Apnea-Hypopnea": "We also
applied an infinite impulse response Butterworth low-pass filter
(cutoff = 1.2 Hz) to reduce noise for a prospective nonlinear
analysis in time domain"

Comment: Marcus, great *pure-math* answer , for pure math Merry. ;-) Btw. **respiration rate** is actually quite low (one breath per second? Or even less ) so 32 Hz *may* be more than sufficient, and even devoid of much aliasing artefacts, depending on which aspect of breathing s/he wanted to capture... Is it the *pressure* change on some input/output air? Or is it the *air flow rate* ? That's a sufficently slow signal I suppose..

Comment: a Butterworth filter is a good choice if you want flatness of the filter impulse response in the pass band; it's not a good choice if you need fast transition from pass band to stop band or very good attenuation in stop band.

Comment: @Fat32 It's supposed to be airflow :) and indeed, I quite enjoyed that answer!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hmm I see.. I have kind of heard about this from just googling on the Butterworth filter, however, I have no experience in filter design so I just chose to look up literature on the topic. Would you have any suggestions on how to approach the filtering?

Comment: @Merry Oh that's good. I believe (but am not sure) that the *air flow rate* signal vs time will be a sufficiently slowly varying waveform (synchronized to breathing rate), from which you can get workable samples at 32 Hz, even without an anti-aliasing filter. Provided that there's not strong high frequency noise components elsewhere on the electrical line. Of course, proper-anti aliasing is the rule to apply. However, when you **oversample** your signal (which you might be doing) in the case, you can perform the anti-aliasing filtering in the digital afterward too. So give it a try.

Comment: @Fat32 Thanks very much! I am totally new to signal processing, so any resources you can suggest for practical work would be very helpful.

Comment: Oh Marcus, now you’re just showing off!  jk, really above and beyond explanation there, very nice!

Comment: @Merry I think the most practical resource is dsp.se... Also there are some books you can have a look at... Type *practical DSP algorithms* to get some insight... Or better come and ask questions here.

Comment: "so 32 Hz may be more than sufficient,", It depends on the application but, have you seen the standard waveforms for neo-natal's or people with respiratory diseases?  As a signal processing problem, it will make your hair curl.

Comment: @rrogers No I haven't seen such a waveform before. So if it's as crazy as you have implied, then 32 Hz may be insufficient, and higher rates should be used. My guess was that basic breathing rate of (healthy) people is a slow process, but the *definite* answer can only be given by observing the associated waveform on an ocilloscope / spectrum analyser...

Comment: I don't know who your sponsors are but you and they should think carefully before venturing into this arena.  Unless you restrict your instrument's use you _will_ be sued; even if your not "guilty"/at fault.  Typically capnometry is used on _sick_ people big/small/neonatal.   Here is a review: both references are from the 80's-90's (showing how long ago I did the work :) ).   
file:///home/rrogers/Home-data/ee/Bhavani-Shankar1992_Article_CapnometryAndAnaesthesia.pdf,
https://www.worldcat.org/title/atlas-of-capnography/oclc/38248123/editions

Comment: You should look at the current literature!   You are responsible for missing any details that would mislead a doctor.  In my, frustrating, case I went through 10 software designs before the customer told me that they had an analog circuit I was supposed to math; after that it was easy.   But that was only for BPM :)  The moral:  find out the industry/accepted standard.  You have a  moral obligation to at least be knowledgeable of the variety of breathing disorders.   Think about your "use case" and make sure you can defend and enforce it.

Answer (score 3):

1. The Fourier transform of a sampled (discrete time) signal can only have information between -Fs/2 and +Fs/2, and that information repeats such that X(f +Fs) = X(f), such that Fs is the sampling frequency.  This means that when sampling an analog signal, you probably want to low pass that signal to make sure it has no frequencies above Fs/2, the Nyquist frequency. This must be done on the analog signal. If the analog signal does have frequencies above Nyquist, they will ‘alias’, and nothing can be done about it after sampling, unless you know something clever about the signal, but that’s more of a corner case.
2. Periodograms have a length and hop size. The longer the length, the higher the frequency resolution but lower time domain bandwidth. The hop size sets the time domain resolution.  So you can resolve 1Hz with a 10Hz sample rate provided the length is sufficient.

Sorry, I don’t do any machine learning stuff, so can’t help there.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! So to clarify, if the signal is already recorded, i.e. I have the signal as an array in a dataset, an anti aliasing filter is not required?

Comment: @Merry it's no longer *possible*. It might have been required, and you just recorded unusable data...

Comment: Ah I see - I think I had a fundamental misunderstanding of when this filtering is done. Are there any concise resources you could recommend on practical signal processing? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Merry The Engineers and Scientists Guide to DSP is free and worth well more than the price.  I’d start with that.